# Can start mysql Server on Preference pane but can't start that on terminal..on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos, toad, workbench

i installed mysql by dmg and used for few days.
i couldn't start server on Preference Pane and Terminal.
thus i repeated install % uninstall few times.

finally i could start server on preference pane but i can't start server on terminal.

when attempted start server on terminal.
i've got these errors.

========================================================

```
LoganLeeui-MacBook-Pro:support-files Logan$ ./mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 ERROR! Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)

LoganLeeui-MacBook-Pro:support-files Logan$ ./mysql.server stop
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

LoganLeeui-MacBook-Pro:support-files Logan$ ./mysql.server restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
 ERROR! Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)
```

========================================================

i added code into /etc/my.cnf

```
[client]
108 
109 port = 3306
110 socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
111 
112 
113 [mysqld]
114 
115 port = 3306
116 socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
117 datadir = /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/data
118 tmpdir = /tmp
119 
120 [client]
121 default-character-set=utf8
122 [mysql]
123 default-character-set=utf8
124 [mysqld]
125 collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
126 init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
127 character-set-server = utf8
```

how can i fix?

i don't want to face Unknown error anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by my self. 
I could delete but i write the answer for person who suffered this kinda problem.

Delete your mysql account which you made.
Then create them again as CREATE USER command. 
Important) grant them as 
Grant all privileges on *.* to xxx@‘%’ with grant option. 
Flush privileges
And restart your mysql server.

Then you wont face this kinda of error anymore.